# BASH SELECT CASE using list from a file as variables

Tags: bash

```
name01=$(echo "Data 01")
name02=$(echo "Data 02")
echo "Please select data : "
PS3="Answer : "
optionname=(
"$name01"
"$name02"
"$name99")
select opt1 in "${optionname[@]}"
do
    case $opt1 in
        $name01) echo "$name01" ; break ;;
        $name02) echo "$name02" ; break ;;
        $name99) echo "Please enter the data : " ; read "name99" ; break ;;
        *) echo invalid option;;
    esac
done
```

This is part of my current script, and only have 12 data for now, but the amount and name of the data will change over time, so I need the data/variable (name01, name02, name03, ...) imported from a list from a separate text file. Let say the file look like this inside :

```
aa bb
aaaa ccc
ab cdd
```

Need advice,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough. Plus having your read within your `case` statement makes this very confusing. Are you looking to add different logic to every option? And are you attempting to seek for user input prior to using the case statement?

Comment: @RobertSeaman the option is pointing to each line of my text file, and yes, this script need user input to continue.

Comment: But if the options were in a text file, and you have separate logic for each option, how you would you represent that logic within your `case` statement? Your best approach is to scrap the text file altogether and list the options in your `case` statement alone.

Comment: Side note: `name01=$(echo "Data 01")` is the same as `name01='Data 01'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to validate user input against a list of options in a file, then you could simply use `grep`:

Given a list of options in `options.txt`.

```
banana
apple
pear
```

And a script (`option.bash`):

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Please enter your favourite fruit: ' fruit_input

if grep -q -o -x -- "$fruit_input" options.txt; then
    echo "Your favourite fruit is: $fruit_input"
else
    echo "The only fruits you're allowed to choose are:"
    cat options.txt
fi
```

You can use grep to validate that the user entered an allowed option:

```
./option.bash
Please enter your favourite fruit: apple
Your favourite fruit is: apple

./option.bash
Please enter your favourite fruit: cheese
The only fruits you're allowed to choose are:
banana
apple
pear
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the update for my script, list is on `/tmp/name_list`

```
touch /tmp/number_list
touch /tmp/number_name_list
amount=$(cat /tmp/name_list | wc -l)
a=0
while [[ $a -lt $amount ]]; do
    let a=$a+1
    echo $a >> /tmp/number_list
    name=$(sed -n "${a}p" /tmp/name_list)
    echo "$a $name">> /tmp/number_name_list
done

cat /tmp/number_name_list
read -p "Please enter the number or enter new name : " input
if
    grep -q -o -x -- "$input" /tmp/number_list
then
    folder=$(sed -n "${input}p" /tmp/name_list)
    echo "its $folder"
    mkdir /tmp/"$folder"
else
    echo "its $input"
    mkdir /tmp/"$input"
fi
```

Thank you to @Robert Seaman for reminding me to use `if then else` instead of `case`